# NSPredicate matching multiple properties

Tags: iphone, nspredicate

I've looked into filtering my data in my app and I got a recommendation to look at NSPredicate.  I've been looking into it in one of hte Apress books, but I'm having a problem finding an example so I'm trying to create one.

If I had something like this:

```
myObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger age;
```

create some objects and put then into an array.

Then I'm not sure how I would create the prediate to search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's as simple as

`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName == %@) || (lastName == %@) || (age == %i)", <name>, <lastName>, <age>];`