# Filter array in ios checking multiple properties

Tags: iphone, ios, search, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I have an array of custom objects. The custom object look like this

```
@interface User : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *user_Id;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *user_Name;
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSString *user_UserName;
@end
```

I have to filter the array checking 2 properties.That is if I search `a` then it should get list of users filtered from array contains `a` in `user_Name` or `user_Id` .How can i achieve this? For a single property i know[user_Name]

```
NSString *predicateString = @"user_Name MATCHES[c] %@";
NSString *matchString =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @".*%@.*",searchText];
NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateString, matchString];
self.searchResults = [userArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: what about using two of them and merging the results?

Comment: true.but how to merge the results without duplicates?

Comment: as user_Id will be common, loop through one of them and if user_id not in the array add it.

Comment: I just found a straight forward solution.. posting it.

Comment: Soory Lithu, i have to vote-close, as 100% dupe exists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSPredicate matching multiple properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738752/nspredicate-matching-multiple-properties)

Comment: Oov i didnt find that..anyway i got what i was looking for thanks all :)

Comment: Multiple ways to filter an NSArray without always using NSPredicate. Disagree that it's a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can join predicate conditions with `OR`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795), such as:

```
NSString *predicateString = @"(user_Name MATCHES[c] %@) OR (user_Id MATCHES[c] %@)";
```

Alternately, you could filter the array by using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` with an appropriate test block and then `objectsAtIndexes:` to get an array of the objects passing the test.

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me, so used orCompoundQueries and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(user_Name== %@) || (user_Id== %@), <name>,  <id>];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this predicate string

```
NSString *predicateString = @"user_Name MATCHES[c] %@ OR user_Id MATCHES[c] %@";
```