# How to search in multiple string in array in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to search for string entered by user to check in multiple strings.
I have tried using OR, but its not working.

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"address contains[c] %@ || approved contains[c] %@ || businessName contains[c] %@ || city contains[c] %@ || country contains[c] %@ || dealerNo contains[c] %@ || dealerId contains[c] %@ || email contains[c] %@ || fax contains[c] %@ || phone contains[c] %@ || published contains[c] %@ || regionNum contains[c] %@ || state contains[c] %@ || website contains[c] %@ || zip contains[c] %@ || businessName contains[c] %@ || businessName contains[c] %@ || businessName contains[c] %@", searchText];

    //Here address, approved, businessName.... all these string, I want to search in.

    searchResults = [cellData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

   //cellData is my total array
   //searchResults is array after filtering 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filter array in ios checking multiple properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583195/filter-array-in-ios-checking-multiple-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found solution, this is how it works:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
```

{

```
NSPredicate *predicateName = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"address contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicateSSID = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"approved contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatebusiness = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"businessName contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicateCity = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatecountry = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"country contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatedealerNo = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dealerNo contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatedealerId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dealerId contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicateemail = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatefax = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fax contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatephone = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phone contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatepublished = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"published contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicateregionNum = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"regionNum contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatestate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"state contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatewebsite = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"website contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSPredicate *predicatezip = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"zip contains[cd] %@", searchText];
NSArray *subPredicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:predicateName, predicateSSID,predicatebusiness,predicateCity,predicatecountry,predicatedealerNo, predicatedealerId, predicateemail,predicatefax,predicatephone, predicatepublished, predicateregionNum,predicatestate,predicatewebsite,predicatezip, nil];
NSPredicate *orPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subPredicates];
searchResults = [cellData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:orPredicate];
```

}

Here first created NSPredicate for each value, then its array, then created NSPredicate with array using NSCompoundPredicate, then I got my filtered Array. It was a bit complex structure. Thanks to everyone, who tried.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    NSArray *searchResults = [cellData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
    NSLog(@"Result = %@",searchResults);

}
```

For Multiple string use this line

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(address contains[c] %@) || (approved contains[c] %@) || (businessName contains[c] %@) || (city contains[c] %@) || (country contains[c] %@) || (dealerNo contains[c] %@) || (dealerId contains[c] %@) || (email contains[c] %@) || (fax contains[c] %@) || (phone contains[c] %@) || (published contains[c] %@) || (regionNum contains[c] %@) || (state contains[c] %@) || (website contains[c] %@) || (zip contains[c] %@) || (businessName contains[c] %@) || (businessName contains[c] %@) || (businessName contains[c] %@)", searchText];
```

Comment: If `cellData` contains strings then the predicate should be `SELF contains[cd] %@`

Comment: Its working for only one string, but I want to search in multiple strings.

Comment: try replacing name contains[cd] %@ by SELF contains[cd] %@.. Now am updated this in solution

Comment: @Wain using SELF contains[cd] %@ gives following exception: 'Can't use in/contains operator with collection <MyData: 0x17e8c6a0> (not a collection)' Because cellData array is collection of class, on its each index there is MyData class's object.

Answer (score 1):

```
    -(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1 textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
     {
if ([searchText length]==0)
{
  temp_array1 =[array_Main1 mutableCopy];
  temp_array2 =[array_Main2 mutableCopy];
  temp_array3 =[array_Main3 mutableCopy];
}
 else
{
  [temp_array1 removeAllObjects];
  [temp_array2 removeAllObjects];
  [temp_array3 removeAllObjects];
   int g = 0;
   for (int i=0; i< array_Main1.count;i++)
    {
        NSRange Range1 = [[array_Main1 objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange Range2 = [[array_Main2 objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange Range3 = [[array_Main3 objectAtIndex:i] rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (Range1.location != NSNotFound ||  Range2.location != NSNotFound ||  Range3.location != NSNotFound )
        {
            [temp_array1 addObject:[array_Main1 objectAtIndex:g]];
            [temp_array2 addObject:[array_Main2 objectAtIndex:g]];
            [temp_array3 addObject:[array_Main3 objectAtIndex:g]];

        }
        g++;
    }
}
[table reloadData];
}
```